# Regex Repeating Pattern to Capture All HTML Table Column Contents

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I am attempting to capture all column contents within HTML tables. I'm very close, but my regex is only capturing the first column of each table. What do I need to do to capture all of the columns?

Here is my regex and HTML: https://regex101.com/r/jA3sS6/1

Comment: Any reason for not using PHP `DOMDocument`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  Build a state machine (or use frz3993's method. It's probably a state machine under the hood)

Comment: Wow, I wish I'd known about https://regex101.com a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regular expression, use a Parser instead!

Start with this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

To retrieve all `<td>`:

```
foreach( $dom->GetElementsByTagName( 'td' ) as $td )
{
    echo $td->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

To retrieve all `<td class="large-text">`:

```
foreach( $xpath->query( '//td[@class="large-text"]' ) as $td )
{
    echo $td->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- Read **[why you can't parse [X]HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)**